# inserting values to a table using form in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Only the first given value are inserted in table.The variable i is used to increment the index value of tr in the table, it is incrementing but values are not inserting. The others are not added. Can't figure out why. I am new to jquery.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>My first Page</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
var i=0;

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#hello").click(function(){
var a=$("<td></td>").text($("#test1").val());
var b=$("<td></td>").text($("#test2").val());
var c=$("<td></td>").text($("#test3").val());
var d=$("<td></td>").text($("#test4").val());
var e=$("<td></td>").text($("#test5").val());
$($("table tr").eq(i)).after(e).after(d).after(c).after(b).after(a);
i=i+1;
  });
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<h1>Hello Talib</h1>
<div>IT</div>
<div>WILL</div>
<div>DISAPPEAR</div>
</div>
First Name: <input type="text" value="fname" id ="test1"><br>
Last Name: <input type="text" value="lname" id="test2"><br>
Roll Number: <input type="text" value="rnum" id="test3"><br>
Faculty:
<select name="Faculty" id="test4">
<option value="CE">Computer Engineering</option>
<option value="BE">Biomedical Engineering</option>
<option value="CV">Civil Engineering</option>
<option value="TE">Telecommunication Engineering</option>
</select>
<br>
Semester:
<input type="radio" value="1st" name="sem" id="test5">1st
<input type="radio" value="2nd" name="sem" id="test5">2nd
<input type="radio" value="3rd" name="sem" id="test5">3rd
<input type="radio" value="4th" name="sem" id="test5">4th
<input type="radio" value="5th" name="sem" id="test5">5th
<input type="radio" value="6th" name="sem" id="test5">6th
<input type="radio" value="7th" name="sem" id="test5">7th
<input type="radio" value="8th" name="sem" id="test5">8th
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"id="hello">

<table border="1" style="border: solid 1px black">
<tr>
<td>First Name</td>
<td>Last Name</td>
<td>Roll Number</td>
<td>Faculty</td>
<td>Semester</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have a reason for the alphabetized variables, you could just use a for loop instead:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#hello").click(function(){
      $row = $('<tr/>');
      for(i=1; i<=5; i++){
          cellVal = i < 5 ? $("#test"+i).val() : $("input[name=sem]:checked").val();
          $row.append($("<td/>").text(cellVal));
      }
      $('table').append($row);
  });
});
```

But please rethink your checkboxes, you can't have duplicate ids anywhere in your DOM. I've added a work-around but definitely, get rid of those duplicates.

[<kbd>JSFiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/SsE7r/4/)

Comment: Note the duplicated `id` on the semester fields.

Comment: @anOG - how this gets simulated as <tr><td>...</td></tr> ?

Comment: Thanks @RoryMcCrossan - I noticed a little late.

Comment: Can anyone recommend a book for mastering jquery?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should use `append()` to create an element in the DOM at the end of a parent . This saves messing around incrementing a counter. Secondly, your radio buttons contains repeated `id` attributes which is invalid. Change your radio HTML to use a class to group them:

```
<input type="radio" value="1st" name="sem" class="test5">1st
<input type="radio" value="2nd" name="sem" class="test5">2nd
<input type="radio" value="3rd" name="sem" class="test5">3rd
<input type="radio" value="4th" name="sem" class="test5">4th
<input type="radio" value="5th" name="sem" class="test5">5th
<input type="radio" value="6th" name="sem" class="test5">6th
<input type="radio" value="7th" name="sem" class="test5">7th
<input type="radio" value="8th" name="sem" class="test5">8th
```

You can then use this class along with the `:checked` selector to get the chosen value. Note the use of `append()` here:

```
$("#hello").click(function () {
    var $tr = $('<tr />');
    $tr.append($("<td />", { text: $("#test1").val() }))
    $tr.append($("<td />", { text: $("#test2").val() }))
    $tr.append($("<td />", { text: $("#test3").val() }))
    $tr.append($("<td />", { text: $("#test4").val() }))
    $tr.append($("<td />", { text: $(".test5:checked").val() }))
    $tr.appendTo('table');
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2GfhF/)

Answer (score 0):

what about this:

just cache your values in variables and then concatenate them into one variable

**http://jsfiddle.net/nC6FJ/2/**

```
var i=0;

$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#hello").click(function(){
        var a = $("#test1").val(),
            b = $("#test2").val(),
            c = $("#test3").val(),
            d = $("#test4").val(),
            e = $("#test5").val(),
            tdHTML = "<td>"+a+"</td>"+
                 "<td>"+b+"</td>"+
                 "<td>"+c+"</td>"+
                 "<td>"+d+"</td>"+
                 "<td>"+e+"</td>";
        $("table tr").eq(i).after(tdHTML);
        i=i+1;
    });
});
```

also you dont have to nest your jQuery element object into another